# Which scope to use in Kotlin to retrieve remote data in a ViewModel

Tags: kotlin

Currently I'm using a viewModelScope to launch a coroutine which in turns retrieves data from a remote server and caches the results in a local ROOM database.

My question is if I should use instead a GlobalScope to launch the coroutine to get such remote data, as the retrieval/caching can be interrupted if the app is sent to the background when using the viewModelScope.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this (https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-best-practices#create-coroutines-data-layer) which also links to this handy blog post that goes into more depth (https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-patterns-for-work-that-shouldnt-be-cancelled-e26c40f142ad). That post also explains why you should avoid GlobalScope, and recommends creating your own reusable scope in an `Application` class. Basically, it comes down to how long the coroutine should live - if it's a background fetch operation, you probably don't want it to die with the UI

Answer (score 1):

Android discourages to perform continuous running tasks in the background since it uses battery and memory in the main thread. However, if you specifically need code to run in the background, consider using [Background Services](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service) or [Work Manager](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) which is also responsible for starting background tasks.